# play framework disable browser debugger in dev mode

Tags: java, playframework

I'm working on a play2. 6 application using Java, and I hosted my application dev mode. 
I want to know how to disable the debug view in this mode and redirect to another error page that a created automatically.
404 errors to `404err.scala.html` 
java errors to `500err.sacala.html`
databaseConnction to `dbDownErr.scala.html` 
all the solutions i found are a production mode solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not recommend hosting your app in dev mode. It's really easy to deploy your app with play.

Nonetheless if you really want to do that, you could override the default error handler: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaErrorHandling#Supplying-a-custom-error-handler

Check the `HttpErrorHandler` interface to know what are the methods to override

Comment: thanks ! that works  (i deployed my app because my client want to follow my progress ) BUT , when the connexion to database is interrupted i still get the code error on my browser how to solve that ?

Comment: This comes from the dev mode. If at startup, the db is not available, the application won't start in prod mode. In dev mode, the exception is displayed.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what if the connection does the DB is established with success (dev mode) but after there were a disconnection from the sql server how to redirect to a custom error page?

Comment: I thought the error handler would handle this case. Does this exception skip the error handler ?

Comment: yes, only in this case i can't show my custom error page